# golang: Send http request with certificate

Tags: https, go

For first I am newbie in golang.

I try to send https request. I create http.Client like this:

```
func httpClient(c *Config) (httpClient *http.Client) {
cert, _ := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(c.CertFile, c.KeyFile)

ssl := &tls.Config{
    Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{cert},
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
}

ssl.Rand = rand.Reader
return &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: ssl,
    },
}
}
```

But as result I get `local error: no renegotiation`.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a problem with the remote server you're accessing, but it is a known problem (with Microsoft Azure services for one).

There may be a workaround on the way for go1.4, but until then the go client still doesn't support TLS renegotiation.

Relevant issue: https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5742

Comment: I saw this link before but thought somebody know the concrete solution. Interesting go-curl will help me? I will try tomorrow. Thanks for answer!

Comment: go-curl not helps me. May I do same behaviour by another way?

Comment: Can you run your desired request using curl directly? That's usually a good way to troubleshoot.

Comment: Yes, I tried to run desired request by next code: `curl -X POST --cacert /Users/sergio/.ssh/betfair.crt --data "username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD" --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "X-Application: APPLICATION_KEY" https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/certlogin` or by go-curl https://gist.github.com/sergio1990/59d8d675e0bf80789bfb but result was always same: `{"loginStatus":"CERT_AUTH_REQUIRED"}`. There is problem with attaching certificate as I understand. `curl 7.30.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0) libcurl/7.30.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5`

Comment: Hm... It's very insteresting: on server with Ubuntu 14.04 is all works, but there are problems on my local Mac OS 10.9.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 golang-curl works well! Problem is fully solved.

Comment: @SergeyGernyak I think it depends on the curl version. I had to do this to get it to work with go-curl `easy.Setopt(curl.OPT_SSLVERSION, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though renegotiation (and client certificate authentication) was previously unsupported. This looks to have been fixed by commit https://github.com/golang/go/commit/af125a5193c75dd59307fcf1b26d885010ce8bfd